# Authorization for someone to cash a government check issued to me while I am residing abroad

Tags: check, international

I live in Sweden. I was issued a check from the US Government but Swedish banks do not honour foreign checks ... and the US Government refuses to put the amount directly into my Swedish account.

If I send my check to a family member in the US will she be able to cash it or put it into her own American account? The amount is less than $2,000.

Comment: Back in the day, there would be American Express branches in most big European cities.  They'd have been able to help you.  Of course, it's not 1980 anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can endorse the check to a third party. On the back of the check, there's a section where you can write "Pay to the order of [family member name]" Then sign your name below the endorsement.